# how can I make png image to gif image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

I want to change png image to gif image using python3.6 how can I do that?  i'm making a GUI program with tkinter and i haver to change png to gif image so i can display on my program please help

```
tk = Tk()
tk.configure(bg = 'white')

tk.title("SearchKeyWord V2.0")

canvas = Canvas(tk,width = 880, height = 550,bd = 0,highlightthickness = 0)

canvas.pack()
txt = Entry(tk)
txt.place(relx = .9,rely = .3,anchor = "c")
LOGO = PhotoImage(file = 'SKW-LOGO.gif')
button_1 = PhotoImage(file = 'button.gif')
button_2 = PhotoImage(file = 'button_news_1d.gif')
button_3 = PhotoImage(file = 'button_news_1w.gif')




button = tkinter.Button(tk,image = button_1,command = search)
button_news_1d = tkinter.Button(tk,image = button_2)
button_news_1w = tkinter.Button(tk,image = button_3)

canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor = NW, image = LOGO)
button.place(relx=.8, rely=.5, anchor="c")
button_news_1d.place(relx =.8,rely = .7, anchor = "c" )
button_news_1w.place(relx =.8,rely = .9, anchor = "c" )


tk.update()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try PIL or pillow https://python-pillow.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pillow’s `ImageTk` to load the image directly as png.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
image_o = Image.open("photo.png")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_o)

#  Use image as to how you would in tkinter 

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, image = image)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Unlike tkinter‘s PhotoImage, which limits you to use only a certain type of images including the widespread gif file, ImageTk’s PhotoImage can take any PIL recognizable image type by having pillow to load it first.

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html

If you don’t have pillow yet, do `pip install pillow`

---

***Added***: (thanks to Mike - SMT’s valuable comment)

**In newer releases of tk/tkl 8.6+, tk natively supports png image format.**

Warning: this version of tk isn’t supported in some python interpreters.

https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html

Comment: hmm. then can I save the loaded image as gif using pillow?

Comment: You can... but you wouldn’t need to unless the actually wanted it to be gif, using pillow will help you avoid needing to convert to gif and allows you to directly use png in tkinter

Comment: oh i got it Thanks :)

Comment: Added note that the latest versions of 'tkinter 8.6+' support 'png' natively.

Comment: @Mike-SMT thank you for added this, I incorporated in the answer